# Trying to access a piano music app from my iPad using my new Novation Impulse 25 MIDI Keyboard Controller

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I have been using a Piano Adventures music app on my iPad for a couple of years. Recently I got a new Novation Impulse 25 MIDI keyboard controller which will allow me to access the Piano Adventures internal synthesizer if I use my MIDI controller keyboard to play the practice exercises. It will tell me information such as what notes I hit were accurate with the exercise and what notes I missed, among several other features.

I contacted the Piano Adventures tech office and I received information regarding how to go to the iPad music app settings menu to adjust the settings within the app so that my MIDI keyboard should be playing the music app.

However, I am brand new to using a MIDI keyboard and I believe there are some settings I need to adjust on the Impulse 25 end in order for my MIDI keyboard to recognize the iPad music app. And yes, I am using the Apple USB cable adapter and this works fine, as it does power my Impulse 25.

I have read the User Manual and I have tried some adjustments to the Impulse settings, but so far nothing has worked that activates the handshake between my MIDI controller and my iPad music app.

Thanks for any suggestions any of you may have - I would love to finally start playing my Piano Adventures music on my MIDI keyboard and to be able to track my performance!

/Joe

Comment: have you seen this video? may be it can help you ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnAXUznNMP4

Comment: Great video suggestion...really enjoyed it!  As it turns out, I had posted my question on another forum too and after I read a response it made me go back to the settings in the app itself, not the Novation Impulse keyboard, and I adjusted the MIDI In setting, and now it is working!  Thank you so much for your feedback though; I picked up some helpful info on the YouTube video you suggested.  Take care... /Joe